# MongoDB : sharded cluster, add a shard that contains all data

Tags: database, replication, mongodb

Last year, I set up a set up a mongoDB production cluster.
It has a router, 3 config server, and 3 shards (wuth a big database and data spread between them). We wanted to add other shards to form replicasets but for various reasons (such as storage space), we still haven't.
It this situation, backup is a pain in the butt. I think mongodump is my only option (or else i have to shut down everything). but mongorestore is forcing me to restore everything on a single server, and only then re-shard everything.

I wanted to know if it was possible to maybe deploy a new server separated from the rest of the cluster that would receive the full databases from the cluster presented earlier? It would have to be synced (asynchronous or synchronous).

This is only a temporary solution, but I didn't find any info in the docs or on the web... It would allow us to have to server ready in case something bad happens to our cluster.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I think mongodump is my only option (or else i have to shut down everything)

Backing up a sharded cluster with `mongodump` generally isn't the best option in terms of production impact, ease of use, or efficiency. With this approach you are effectively exporting collection data and index definitions with `mongodump` and then rebuilding databases in another environment with `mongorestore`. Dumping data may have a significant effect on performance / working set as all data has be read through the MongoDB server; restoring may also take longer as indexes will need to be rebuilt.

Alternative (and less impactful) approaches would be backing up with [file system snapshots](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-sharded-cluster-with-filesystem-snapshots/) or a commercial service such as [MongoDB Cloud Manager](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/cloud-manager). A full backup solution should provide continuous backup with regular snapshots and retention policies. For example, see Cloud Manager's [Backup Preparations](https://docs.cloudmanager.mongodb.com/core/backup-preparations/) guide.

> mongorestore is forcing me to restore everything on a single server, and only then re-shard everything.

The MongoDB manual has tutorials to [Back Up a Sharded Cluster with Database Dumps](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-sharded-cluster-with-database-dumps/) and [Restore a Sharded Cluster with Database Dumps](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/restore-sharded-cluster/#restore-a-sharded-cluster-with-database-dumps). Following the documented approach you do not have to re-shard when restoring from backup, however there are multiple steps to coordinate a consistent backup & restore of each of your shards and the cluster metadata.

If you are using `mongodump` to export all data for a backup (rather than following the sharded cluster backup procedure), `mongorestore` will not recreate collections with sharding options. However, you can set up sharding first and `mongorestore` into existing sharded collections. For example, if you wanted to restore a single sharded collection you could create an empty collection with the desired shard key and then [pre-split chunks](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-chunks-in-sharded-cluster/) before importing your data.

> I wanted to know if it was possible to maybe deploy a new server separated from the rest of the cluster that would receive the full databases from the cluster presented earlier? It would have to be synced (asynchronous or synchronous).

You could use a solution like [Mongo Connector](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/wiki/Usage-with-MongoDB) to replicate data from your sharded cluster to a backup MongoDB deployment. This will ensure you have another deployment on standby, but does not provide for usual backup requirements like being able to recover to a previous snapshot or point-in-time.

> This is only a temporary solution, but I didn't find any info in the docs or on the web... It would allow us to have to server ready in case something bad happens to our cluster.

If you need a temporary solution I would strongly consider using a commercial backup service for your production data until you have more time to evaluate alternatives.

Disaster planning should consider fault tolerance and backup/restore times for both data and infrastructure:

- For normal operational issues (eg. hardware/server failures) you should plan appropriate redundancy and failover using replica sets to back each of your shards. Replica set members can be distributed across multiple data centres and/or geographies depending on your requirements for disaster recovery and failover.
- An effective backup strategy will prepare you for unexpected situations where you need to recover some or all data because that data is unavailable in your production environment. The most extreme case would be needing to rebuild your sharded cluster from a backup, but more common cases are accidental deletion or modification of data due to user or software error.

You should consider aspects like backup automation, backup isolation, recovery objectives (eg. snapshots vs point-in-time), recovery time goals, and production impact in order to create the most appropriate disaster recovery plan for your deployment.

For more information I suggest reading MongoDB's white paper on [Backup and its Role in Disaster Recovery](http://s3.amazonaws.com/info-mongodb-com/MongoDB-backup-disaster-recovery.pdf).